# Как вывести все числа месяца, и дни недели к ним

Tags: java, javafx, дата

Доброго дня! Необходимо сделать таблицу как на скриншоте, подскажите каким образом это сделать правильнее и проще, datepicker как я понял в такой ситуации не поможет. Уже написал combobox который дает выбрать месяц,через enum, и там же указано кол-во дней в месяце, но тогда встает вопрос как корректно сделать отображение дней недели.

PS. Есть ощущение что можно как-то проще решить подобную задачу,заранее спасибо

PS.Получилось реализовать, код выкладываю,может кому пригодиться. Если есть мысли как улучшить, всегда рад услышать.

```
public class EnMonth {

public  enum Month {
    JANUARY(0, 31, "Январь" ),
    FEBRUARY(1, 28, "Февраль" ),
    MARCH(2, 31, "Март" ),
    APRIL(3, 30, "Апрель" ),
    MAY(4, 31, "Май" ),
    JUNE(5, 30, "Июнь" ),
    JULY(6, 31, "Июль" ),
    AUGUST(7, 31, "Август" ),
    SEPTEMBER(8, 30, "Сентябрь" ),
    OCTOBER(9, 31, "Октябрь" ),
    NOVEMBER(10, 30, "Ноябрь" ),
    DECEMBER(11, 31, "Декабрь" );

    private final int _days;
    private final String _name;
    private final int _nomberOfMonth;

    public int get_days() {return _days;}
    public int get_nomberOfMonth() {return _nomberOfMonth;}
    public String get_name() {return _name;}

    Month(int nomberOfMonth, int days, String name) {
        _nomberOfMonth = nomberOfMonth;
        _days = days;
        _name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return get_name( );
    }
}

public static ObservableList<String> dOf (Month month){
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(2017, month._nomberOfMonth, 0);
    SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.EE" );
    for(int i = 0; i < month._days; i++){
        System.out.println(d.format(calendar.getTime()));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1); //Прибавляем сутки

    list.add( d.format( calendar.getTime() ) );};
    return list;
}}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: вам нужно вывести только одну неделю? или вы хотите весь месяц?

Comment: Весь месяц, неделю просто для примера привел.

Comment: добавьте ваш вариант в вопрос